# SSL Pinning bypass using retrofit

Tags: frida, bypass

I am using issue that Info Sec team can bypass my **SSL certificate using frida and Objection** so I attached SSL certificate while calling the api using retrofit. please provide me a solution that no one can bypass my certificate. Even I added certificate validation in my code.
when info sec team run the application first time they are showing certificate validation error so after this they run a script of Frida or objection script then they bypass the certificate and easily login to the application and started getting the apis responses.
Here is my code:

```
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun taboraCC(
        context: Application,
        httpLoggingInterceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor,
        apiHeadersInterceptor: ApiHeadersInterceptor
    ): OkHttpClient {

        val okHttpBuilder = certificatePinning(context)
        okHttpBuilder
            .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
            .addInterceptor(apiHeadersInterceptor)
            .connectTimeout(CLIENT_TIME_OUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(CLIENT_TIME_OUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(CLIENT_TIME_OUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        return okHttpBuilder.build()
    }


    private fun certificatePinning(mContext: Context):
            OkHttpClient.Builder {
        var mCertificateFactory: CertificateFactory =
            CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")
        var mInputStream = mContext.resources.openRawResource(R.raw.digital_kp_gov_pk)
        var mCertificate: Certificate = mCertificateFactory.generateCertificate(mInputStream)
        mInputStream.close()
        val mKeyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType()
        val mKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(mKeyStoreType)
        mKeyStore.load(null, null)
        mKeyStore.setCertificateEntry("digital.kp.gov.pk", mCertificate)
        val mTmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm()
        val mTrustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(mTmfAlgorithm)
        mTrustManagerFactory.init(mKeyStore)
        val mTrustManagers = mTrustManagerFactory.trustManagers
        val mSslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")
        mSslContext.init(null, mTrustManagers, null)
        val mSslSocketFactory = mSslContext.socketFactory
        val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        builder.sslSocketFactory(mSslSocketFactory, mTrustManagers[0] as X509TrustManager)
        builder.hostnameVerifier { _, _ -> true }
        return builder
    }
```

How can i safe my certificate that will not bypass using Frida and Objection?

Comment: An app written in Java/Kotlin on a rooted device can always be modified using Frida in a way so that your TLS pinning code will allow non-pinned certificates. You may be able to write code that prevents Objectsion from "unpining" it, but if someone updates the Objection script based on your code that it will work again. If you want to secure your app buy an app protector that prevents Frida from attaching.

Comment: Note that your current code is not a real pinning code, it simply changes the trusted CA list to the certificates in `R.raw.digital_kp_gov_pk`. An SSL pinner is usually an additional check. See e.g. https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/CertificatePinner.html however I assume that this check can also be pypassed by Objection.